# How to change font style of text on image in java?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am creating image dynamically and writing on image, there are limited set of font style.I want to change it to some other style in `"Kunstler Script"`. 
here is my code:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, 
                                 imageHeight,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 65));
    g2.setColor(Color.orange);
    g2.drawString(" MY IMAGE", 350, 70);
    g2.drawLine(350, 80, 1000, 80);
    g2.dispose();
    File out = new File("E:/" + IMAGE + "_1.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
```

here i want to change the font style

```
        g2.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 65));
```

at the place of `"SANS_SERIF"` i want some another font like `"Kunstler Script"`
please anybody help me to FIX it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Kuntsler Script is an available font, it's as simple as:

`g2.setFont(new Font("Kunstler Script", Font.BOLD, 65));`

Comment: +1 It's better to get a list of available fonts and then change if the font exists.